# How to Replace the Current Handlebars Template in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I am working on a simple Ember CRUD app and ran into an issue swapping a "display" template with an "edit" template.  Here is my route configuration:

```
App.Router.map(function(){ //map URLs to templates
   this.resource('contacts',{path: '/contacts'}, function(){
       this.resource('contact', {path: '/contact/:contact_id'}, function(){
           this.route('edit');
           this.route('create');
           this.route('delete');
       });
   });
});
```

The follow template displays my model.  I want the link-to to replace the display template with the edit template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="contact">
        <h3>{{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}</h3>
        <h4>Contact Details</h4>
            {{ email }} 
        <br/>
        {{ phone }}
        <br/>
        {{#link-to "contact.edit" this}}edit{{/link-to}}
</script>
```

Unfortunately when a user clicks the `#link-to "contacdt.edit"`, the view is rendered in the {{outlet}} (I only added the {{outlet}} for debugging).  The edit template also doesn't seem to bind correctly to the current model.

Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/noelstieglitz/LGqGP/) for a complete example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default a template is rendered in the main outlet of the parent template. Your `contact.edit` template have the `contact` as parent template, because of your route hierachy. And you need to render inside of the `contacts` template.

You can override the `renderTemplate` method from `App.ContactEditRoute`, to get the desired behavior:

```
App.ContactEditRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.find(App.Contact, params.contact_id);
    },
    actions: {
        save: function () {
            var newContact = this.modelFor('contact.edit');
            this.transitionTo('contact', newContact);
        }
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('contact.edit', { into: 'contacts' })
    }
});
```

This is docs for template rendering http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

Here is the fiddle with the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/y58vB/